# Is it possible to query Firebase Firestore by both a location and age range?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I query my Firestore database based on age range and location.

For example, let's say I want to get all users that are between the age of 18 and 30, and are within 5 miles me.

Here's a simplified version of my current database structure.

```
users
  uid_0
    age: 21
  uid_1
    age: 24
```

To filter by age parameters, I know I can do this:

```
// Swift

db.collection("users")
  .whereField("age", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 18)
  .whereField("age", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 30)
```

For location, I've read Firebase's [geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc) can be used, which would add an additional node such as:

```
_geofire
  uid_0:
    g: "asdaseeefef"
    l: 
      0: 52.2101515118818
      1: -0.3215188181881
  uid_1:
    g: "oposooksok"
    l: 
      0: 50.1234567898788
      1: -0.8789999595988
```

But I'm unsure how to add a location query on top of my original gender+age query (tbh I'm uncertain how to make a location query even by itself). But in regards to combining the two, my main concern is that the Firestore docs specify that you can only apply a range filter on one field, and I already am applying one for the `age` field.

Is it possible to filter by location while also filtering by an age range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Frank van Puffelen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72818922/16602527), I think the best solution (at least in the case of an app that needs to scale) is the pre-filtering option because we can keep database storage and read costs at a minimum (explained under the **Best Solution** header further down.

### Shortcomings of other options

**Post-filtering shortcoming:**

Since we could (in theory) have millions of users within a 100 mile radius, the *post-filtering age* option would require fetching all that data at once, which means we couldn't take advantage of Firebase's cost/time-saving `.limit(to:)` method and things would get expensive and time-consuming, fast.

**GeoAgeHash shortcoming:**

Frank's `GeoAgeHash` idea is interesting and theoretically possible, but I don't believe this would be financially feasible either because – just how a GeoHash requires up to 9 queries – by adding the 3rd dimension of age (the first two being lat and long), it would raise the number of queries for a single search to potentially 9 * 82 (assuming you were querying users with ages between 18 and 100 resulting in the 82 options). And this would eat up your Firestore limit of 50K reads per day pretty quickly.

### Best Solution

**Pre-filtering:**

*EDIT: Turns out there is a major downfall to this solution as well in that Firestore requires a composite index to be made for each tag (below) since we are using a range clause for the Geohash, so that nears the limit of 200 tags allowed. If you are querying by other items as well, a composite index is required for each combination which could put you over, not to mention it's very time consuming to make that many indexes.*

With that being said, I think the pre-filtering option is the best. For *precise* age filtering, you would just need to make sure you had a tag for each possible age.

*For example:* `isOver18`, `isOver19`, `isOver20`... tags to query against for the minimum age constraint, and then `isUnder100`, `isUnder99`, all the way down for the upper-age limit constraint.

And actually, more realistically, you would should be storing birthdates instead of ages (since ages would need to be checked each day and possibly updated to remain accurate).

Therefore, for querying purposes, you would store birth *year* tags instead of age tags, such as birth year `isOver1900`, `isOver1901` and up, then `isUnder2004`, `isUnder2003` and down.

In short, each user doc would need 82 `isOver` tags, and 82 `isUnder` tags, assuming you are planning for queries between the ages of 18 and 100 (which results in the 82 different ages).

### Example Database Structure

```
Users Collection
  userDoc1
    birthDate: TimeInterval // I like to use TimeIntervalSince1970
    isOver1900: Bool
    isOver1901: Bool
    isOver1902: Bool
    ...etc...
    
    isUnder2004: Bool
    isUnder2003: Bool
    isUnder2002: Bool
    ...etc...
  userDoc2
    ...
  ...
```

### Example Usage

```
// Assuming it's 2022, and you want to query users between the ages of 24 and 30

db.collection("Users")
  .whereField("isUnder1998", isEqualTo: true)  // filters >= 23
  .whereField("isOver1991", isEqualTo: true)   // filters <= 31

// Note: we must filter one year extra for the `isOver` clause because technically there could be some people born at the end of 1991 that are still 30, depending on what time of the year the query is made. These edge cases can easily be filtered out client-side.
```

Answer (score 2):

Firestore (and many other NoSQL databases) can only perform relational conditions, such as `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo`/`isLessThanOrEqualTo`/`startAt`/`endAt`, on a single field, due to how their indexes work behind the scenes.

To allow you to perform geoqueries on such a database, libraries such as GeoFire use so-called GeoHash values, which magically merge the two latitude and longitude values into a single value (the `g` in your data structure) that you can perform a range condition on. It's quite magical really. I did a talk on the topic a few years ago, which I highly recommend checking out: [Geo-querying Firebase and Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).

---

Now if you'd **also** like to filter on another property such as age, you'd have to figure out a way to express the value of age into a single type with the longitude and latitude in a way that all three values can be filtered in one go. So you'd have to come up with a GeoHashAndAge type, which (while definitely interesting) seems a bit beyond what most of us are willing to go through.

---

That unfortunately leaves you with only two options: you can either pre-filter the data or post-filter it.

Pre-filtering means that you add one or more fields to each document that allow you to perform the necessary age filter *without* needing a relational condition. For example, if a use-case in your app is that you want people over 18, add a field `isOver18` to each document with a boolean value, and you can filter on that with an equality check, which *can* be combined with the range filter on the geohash. This may not be possible for all use-cases, but when it is possible it allows you to leave the filtering to the database.

Post-filtering is simplest: you just perform the age filtering in your application code after retrieving the documents from Firestore. This always works, but of course means that you're reading more documents that are needed.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think either of the latter two options will work in my case. The pre-filtering option requires the age to be continually updated each day for it to be accurate, so that is why I am actually storing birthdates and performing a relational query on that already.

Comment: The post-filtering option wouldn't be very realistic in my case either because a given 100 mile radius might require downloading potentially thousands and thousands of user profiles on each query (whereas now I paginate and limit the query to 50 profiles at a time).

Comment: Your `GeoHashAndAge` seems intriguing; I will have to look into that. I wonder how feasible it is to create something like that...

Comment: I don't think the `GeoAgeHash` is really financially feasible because – just how a `GeoHash` requires up to 9 queries – by adding the 3rd dimension of age (the first two being lat and long), it would raise the number of queries potentially required to 9 * 82 (assuming you were querying ages 18 to 100 for 82 options), and this would likely eat up your Firestore limit of 50K reads per day pretty quickly.