# Geoflutterfire with where condition `isGreaterThan` not working

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query time with condition `isGreaterThan`, but it doesn't show data.
The code is correct, but I don't know problem.

I want to show data time isGreater selected time.

I think to there is problem in Geoflutterfire with condition `isGreaterThan`.

```
_setStream() async {
    _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    var pos = await location.getLocation();
    double lat = pos.latitude!;
    double lng = pos.longitude!;
    print('timeeeeeeeee$_time');

    int _ti = Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - 999 * 60 * widget.time;
    
    var ref = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('now')
        .where('gender', isEqualTo: widget.gender)
        .where('time', isGreaterThan: _ti)
        .orderBy('time', descending: true);

    GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: lat, longitude: lng);

    stream = radius.switchMap((rad) {
      var collectionReference = ref;
      return geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference).within(
          center: center, radius: rad, field: 'location', strictMode: true);
    });

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });

    stream = geo.collection(collectionRef: ref).within(
        center: center,
        radius: widget.distance,
        field: 'location',
        strictMode: true);
    stream!.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
      documentList.forEach((element) {
        print("from data .......element");
        print(element.data());
        final data = element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final GeoPoint point = data['location']['geopoint'];
        print("from data .......latitude");
        print(point.latitude);
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore queries can only perform range conditions (`>=` and such) on a single field. When you use GeoFire, it already needs to perform this condition on the geohash value to perform the geoquery, so you can't perform a range condition on any other field.

If you want to understand why that is, I recommend watching this video on [implementing geoqueries on Firebase's NoSQL databases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).

If also recommend checking this answer I gave recently on adding an additional range filter to a geoquery, which covers common workarounds: [Is it possible to query Firebase Firestore by both a location and age range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812030/is-it-possible-to-query-firebase-firestore-by-both-a-location-and-age-range/72818922#72818922)